# can anyone give a tiny example to explain the params of tf.random.categorical?

Tags: python, tensorflow

tensorflow's site gives this example

```
tf.random.categorical(tf.log([[10., 10.]]), 5)
```

produces a tensor that "has shape [1, 5], where each value is either 0 or 1 with equal probability"

I have already known, the basic [demo](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/categorical), the meaning of `tf.log([[10., 10.]])`.

what I want to know is what does [batch_size, num_classes] do, can anyone give a tiny example to explain the params?

Comment: would you happen to know what the `[-1,0].numpy()` parameter is here:  `predicted_id = tf.random.categorical(predictions, num_samples=1)[-1,0].numpy()` found at the Colab notebook here:  https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/text/text_generation ?

Comment: @mLstudent33 more than a year late to the party but it means sample taken (i.e. 0th sample (the only sample if num_samples = 1) for the last batch (batch = -1).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As you note, [`tf.random.categorical`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/categorical) takes two parameters:

- `logits`, a 2D float tensor with shape `[batch_size, num_classes]`
- `num_samples`, an integer scalar.

The output is a 2D integer tensor with shape `[batch_size, num_samples]`.

Each "row" of the `logits` tensor (`logits[0, :]`, `logits[1, :]`, ...) represents the event probabilities of a different [categorical distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution). The function does not expect actual probability values, though, but unnormalized log-probabilities; so the actual probabilities would be `softmax(logits[0, :])`, `softmax(logits[1, :])`, etc. The benefit of this is that you can give basically any real values as input (e.g. the output of a neural network) and they will be valid. Also, it's trivial to use specific probability values, or proportions, using logarithms. For example, both `[log(0.1), log(0.3), log(0.6)]` and `[log(1), log(3), log(6)]` represent the same probability, where the second class is three times as likely as the first one but only half as likely as the third one.

For each row of (unnormalized log-)probabilities, you get `num_samples` samples from the distribution. Each sample is an integer between `0` and `num_classes - 1`, drawn according to the given probabilities. So, the result is the 2D tensor with shape `[batch_size, num_samples]` with the sampled integers for each distribution.

EDIT: A small example of the function.

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.random.set_random_seed(123)
    logits = tf.log([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
                     [0., 1., 2., 3.]])
    num_samples = 30
    cat = tf.random.categorical(logits, num_samples)
    print(sess.run(cat))
    # [[3 3 1 1 0 3 3 0 2 3 1 3 3 3 1 1 0 2 2 0 3 1 3 0 1 1 0 1 3 3]
    #  [2 2 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 1 3 3 3 2 3 2 2 1 3 3 3 3 3 2]]
```

In this case, the result is an array with two rows and 30 columns. The values in the first row are sampled from a categorical distribution where every class (`[0, 1, 2, 3]`) has the same probability. In the second row, the class `3` is the most likely one, and class `0` has just no probability of being sampled.

Comment: what happens to the probabilities in the second row to make `3` most likely and `0` have no probability of being sampled?

Comment: @mLstudent33 As I try to explain in the answer, the probabilities of each element on each row are computed as the softmax of the given values. Since the values in the second row are `[log(0), log(1), log(2), log(3)]` (here `log(0)` can be considered minus infinity), the probabilities will be `[0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6]`.

Comment: when I did:  `from scipy.special import softmax
np.set_printoptions(precision=5)
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = np.array([0., 1., 2., 3.])
print(x)

x = np.log(x)

print(x)

probs = softmax(x)

print(probs)
` I got different probabilities of `[0.      0.16667 0.33333 0.5    ]`

Comment: @mLstudent33 You're right, sorry, those are the right probabilities (the ones I put before add up to 1.2 instead of one). The point is that the proportions between the values are maintained (value three is three times as likely as value one).

Comment: @jdehesa  Why there should be a log ops, I see many network architectures, their 'logits' just the raw output of the final layer. like, `logits = keras.layers.Dense(output_size)`, then use `tf.random.categorical(logits, 1)` to choose one or more. Is there a `log` or `softmax` operator inner `tf.random.categorical(logits, 1)`?

Comment: @HuXixi You do not need a log operation, I just used it in the example so that the probabilities of each class were proportional to the numbers I used (so e.g. class 3 is three times as likely as class 1). You can use it with any input as logits, a layer output or anything else.

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks for your kindly reply. So is there an inner `softmax` operation in function `tf.random.categorical(logits, 1)`? to convert the arbitrary `logits` to some kinds of a `probability distrubution`?

Comment: @HuXixi You can think of it like that, yes. I don't know if it literally computes a softmax function inside or if it just does the random sampling in a way that is equivalent, but for all purposes you can consider that a softmax is performed and the results are the actual probabilities.

Comment: @jdehesa Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this simple example will help.

`tf.random.categorical` takes two parameters:

- `logits`,  with shape `[batch_size, num_classes]`
- `num_samples`

Ex:

`list_indices.shape = (4, 10)`

`sampled_indices = tf.random.categorical(list_indices, num_samples=1)`

`sample_indices` will be

```
tf.Tensor(
[[2]
 [9]
 [4]
 [7]], shape=(4, 1), dtype=int64)
```

which means to take `1` `num_samples` out of `10` `num_classes` for each row of `4` rows (`batch_size`)