# Text Generation in Deep Learning Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, text, deep-learning, data-science

I am currently doing text generation in tensorflow. After training the model, when predicting the text and decoding the numbers to text why we used tf.random.categorical(predictions, num_samples=1)[-1,0].numpy??

Answer (score 1):

**1.:** `tf.random.categorical` just returns one of the argument numbers (not the argument itself) that have the greatest probability, based on the probability distribution that it takes as an argument - `predictions` in this case. It only returns one since we set `num_samples=1`.

(For a better answer on what exactly `tf.random.categorical` does, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55063120/can-anyone-give-a-tiny-example-to-explain-the-params-of-tf-random-categorical).)

**2.:** `[-1,0]` is simple index slicing, we just take the first element of the last element.
We take it from the last element since the output is always just the input offset by one position, hence the last element is the new word - and that's what we're searching for in this case.

**3.:** And `numpy()` is being used because we don't (usually) want to deal with tensors at this point. The return of `tf.random.categorical` is a tensor. So we convert it using `numpy()`.